# Word to describe that something changes at the same rate or pace?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English language that describes that something (two or more values or things) is changing (i.e., grows) at the same or similar rate or pace?

Comment: At the same rate of what?

Comment: @Josh61, Speed for example

Comment: You could say it has **uniform growth** or **linear growth**.

Comment: Corrected the question, it's poorly worded, sorry.  English is not my first language.

Comment: You could be more general and say **uniform change**, by the way.

Comment: For two words, there's "growing [in tandem](https://books.google.com/books?id=T_Q8D-ewMkEC&pg=PA196&dq=%22growing+in+tandem%22+%22at+the+same+rate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTkfGZ1LnLAhWF_R4KHQ8GBbkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22growing%20in%20tandem%22%20%22at%20the%20same%20rate%22&f=false)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Synchronized](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synchronized)*** may suggests changes that happen at the same rate:

> - Adj.        - operating in unison; "the synchronized flapping of a bird's wings"

Comment: That suggests more that multiple things are growing at the same time to me, rather than one thing growing at the same rate.

Comment: As this appears to be the OP's intent, have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

An expression for this  that is more idiomatic is to ***"keep pace with"***:

The Collins English Dictionary defines ["keep pace with"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-pace-with) as:

> to proceed at the same speed as

Answer (score 0):

Vlad, we've **synchronous** or **synchronic** to mean changing *in same time* @ exactly the same pace & rythm. **Simultaneous** could be another word to fit your request.